# How to use match & index or lookup function based on a number derived from a time calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I have created a gantt chart to use as part of my rota system. I want to be able to use a formula (either `LOOKUP` or `MATCH` & `INDEX`) to look up the hours worked against another sheet and pull in the break entitlement into another inserted column.

Should be simple enough but I cannot get it to work for the life of me! I suspect it is something to do with the way excel is treating the number (as it has derived from a time calculation (e.g. finish time - start time * 24)

Things I have tried but can't get to work:

1. inserting an additional column & multiplying the answer by 1 so it is recognised as a value;
2. `=VALUE`; `=ABS`; converting to text;
3. Altering the look up table so it is also derived from a time calculation.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction!?

Comment: A sample file might help. Or at least a screenshot, or post some of the values that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after an exact match or an approximate match? Consider this scenario:

[image]

The "time worked" is calculated with `=(B2-A2)*24` - That result does not exist in the lookup table, but in my example I use an approximate match, with 1 (or TRUE) as the last parameter.

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,$G$2:$H$25,2,1)
```

From the Vlookup Help files:

> If an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less
>   than lookup_value is returned.

Note that the first column of the lookup table must be sorted in ascending order to ensure correct results.